# constness for reference class members

Tags: c++, constants

I have a couple of classes one of which keeps reference to the object of other:

```
class Inner {};

class Outer {
    Inner & in;

public:
    Outer(Inner & in) : in(in) {}
};
```

What if I have to create Outer object from const reference to Inner? Am I have to write specific class, say OuterConst, for this?

**UPD**: Any neat solutions using templates? In order to avoid duplication of code in OuterConst class.

**UPD2**: when Inner comes without const it should be modifiable (so I can't just add const to Inner member in current implementation of Outer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a const reference, and use `const_cast` to cast the const away when needed. If you add some runtime checking, it's also safe.

```
class Inner { /* ... */ };

class Outer {
    Inner const & in;
    bool const inIsConst;

    Inner & inMutable()
    {
        if (inIsConst)
            throw std::logic_error("in is const.");
        else
            return const_cast<Inner &>(in);
    }

public:
    Outer(Inner const & in) : in(in), inIsConst(true) {}
    Outer(Inner & in) : in(in), inIsConst(false) {}

    // always safe
    void Foo() { std::cout << in.getFoo(); }

    // will throw if *this was constructed with a const Inner
    void Bar() { inMutable().setFoo(in.getFoo() + 1); }
};
```

And of course you can always split this into two classes: one that cannot change `in`, and another that can.

To do this, you could either derive the class that can change `in` from the class that cannot. Or you could derive both from a common base class which has the common functions as protected members, and make the appropriate ones public with `using Base::Function` in the derived classes.

Answer (score 6):

> What if I have to create Outer object from const reference to Inner?

Well, you can't. That's pretty much it. If Outer only needs to call const member functions of Inner, then make it a const reference- else, your class depends on a mutable Inner object and you should not create an Outer object from a const reference.

Answer (score 3):

The question is whether `Outer` needs to modify `Inner` through `in`. If it does, you should keep `in` as an `Inner &`. In this case if you have a `const Inner &` then of course you can't pass it to `Outer`, because the reference doesn't allow you to modify the referenced `Inner`, but `Outer` does need to modify `Inner`.

If `Outer` doesn't need to modify `Inner`, then you should just write  `in` as a `const Inner &`, in which case `Outer` can be initialized with either an `Inner &` or a `const Inner &`.

You can certainly write:

```
class Inner {};

template <class T>
class Outer {
    T& in;

public:
    Outer(T& in) : in(in) {}
};
```

and then initialize objects of type `Outer<Inner>` or `Outer<const Inner>`. But `Outer` must do something different in these two cases, as otherwise you could just make `in` a `const Inner &`. And in that case you're probably better writing separate classes, so that it's explicit that `Outer` does something different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the two roles of `Outer` are different for different constness'es (one must be edited, the other not), then yes.

But if the two roles are identical (that means no changes are ever made to either a const or a non-const reference) then just always take a `const Inner&` as parameter. If a non-const parameter is passed it will get automatically "promoted" to a `const` one.